# Reading complex nested json object array in angular7

Tags: json, typescript, angular7

I am trying to read the complex  nested JSON array  which looks like below :

```
MyApp1:
  MyApp2:
      MyApp3:
         MyApp4:
            MyApp5:Array(2)
               {Tag: "UI", Technology: "Angular"}
               {Tag: "Backend", Technology: "Spring Boot"}
```

I am trying to store nested array values

```
 {Tag: "UI", Technology: "Angular"}
 {Tag: "Backend", Technology: "Spring Boot"}
```

to mytechnologyArray: any [],

so that I can write ngfor in an HTML page and display those values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let mytechnologyArray = myApp1.myApp2.myApp3.myApp4

after in html

*ngFor=" let element of mytechnologyArray.myApp5" and then use element.Tag or element.Technology to retrive the value